# Legacy iOS app not stretching properly

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a layout issue. I'm trying to make a legacy 3.5in app work on iPhone 5. As soon as I give it the Default-568h@2x.png splash image, the whole app gets aligned to the top of the screen, leaving a huge white gap at the bottom. The autosizing struts and such seem to be set properly (not using Autolayout at the moment), but the thing doesn't stretch to fill the screen. I'm not sure where to look next. I just want my poor tab bar to be at the bottom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using AutoLayout, now is a great time to start. Xcode 5 makes setting constraints a simple exercise.

I suspect that your tab bar frame is hard-coded to certain x, y, width, height coordinates which work well on the 3.5" screen. You can also see how your view renders on taller screens by pressing this button in the Xcode 5 Interface Builder:

[image: expand/collapse image icon]

Comment: There were actually multiple things that had hard-coded coordinates. My bad.